# Regular expression works in test case but not in the real code

Tags: java, regex

I have the following expression representing a playing card pattern:

```
String RCARD1 = "[CDHS]{1}\\:\\d{1,2}[1-14]";
```

when I test it in my test case it works as expected, here is the test case:

```
@Test
    public void checkRegex() throws AssertionError {
        System.out.println("Checking the correctness of card regular expressions");

        String RCARD1 = "[CDHS]{1}\\:\\d{1,2}[1-14]";
        String cardSymbol = "H:14";
        assertTrue(cardSymbol.matches(RCARD1));

        cardSymbol = "C:16";
        assertFalse(cardSymbol.matches(RCARD1));

        cardSymbol = "Z:5";
        assertFalse(cardSymbol.matches(RCARD1));                
    }
```

However when I use this into the Card constructor it always returns false. The following code is slightly modified and I don't check the result, further decipher method  works fine.

```
public Card(String cardSymbol) throws UnknownCardException {

        boolean res = cardSymbol.matches(RCARD1); //fails here !!! 

        if (this.decypherCard(cardSymbol)) {            
        }            
        else throw new UnknownCardException();            
    }
```

So what's the problem here? Why it is not working?

Comment: What do you intend to match with `[1-14]`? Do you know it matches `1` and `4` only? If you need to match numbers from 1 to 14, use `(?:1[0-4]|0?[1-9])`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wP1lJ2/1) - is that what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  `[1-14]` character class matches `1` and `4` only. If you need to match numbers from `1` to `14`, use `(?:1[0-4]|0?[1-9])`.

This regex should work then:

```
^[CDHS]:(?:1[0-4]|0?[1-9])$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wP1lJ2/1).

**NOTE**: With `String.matches()`, you do not need `^` and `$` (you may remove them from the pattern).

Comment: so I was actually lucky with my test which accidentally checks H:14 and that's the only valid value here - thanks